# Difference between Ubuntu Partitions and Windows Partitions

Tags: 12.10, partitioning, windows, wubi

I had first installed ubuntu using wubi through windows, on my drive D, the drive contains some windows files as well, no I want to move my wubi install and make it a regular install on Drive C. MigrateWubi is a good tool I found to accomplish this task, but I am confused with the naming differences in ubuntu and windows. My windows have four partitions in total and ubuntu's `fdisk -l` command shows `sda1`-`sda6` how would I know which sda corresponds to drive C in windows.

Comment: Please edit your question with the output of `sudo fdisk -l` and `sudo blkid`. Are you intending to format the partition corresponding to `C:` and overwrite Windows with the migrated Ubuntu install? (Add info to question). Thanks

Comment: Where it's installed your windows root `?:\Windows`? If it's installed in `C:\` you will have an unbootable system when you remove C.

Comment: Have you tried mounting each drive and browsing its contents? Also, if you knew the size of your C drive you could identify it by listing the partitions and their sizes with the following command `df -H | grep -e sda -e Filesystem`.

Answer (score 1):

What I did is used gnome-disks utility to get the informations about the partitions, it showed me the names of the partitions and their ubuntu version as well i.e. it showed me that C was `sda2` and ubuntu was on `sda3` that was D.

My C drive was not a 83-linux partition so I used the same gnome-disks utility to format the partition and changed to partition type to linux `0x83`.

After setting up the drive I used MigrateWubi to migrate from D to C, and it worked.

---

[Added info by Editor]

One can also see which partition is which by running `sudo blkid` command in an Ubuntu terminal.

Comment: Could you give more detailed explanations? How did you know which partition was C and what was D? How could I differentiate both? Why are you using "83-linux" term, instead ext? How did you set up the drive? And, I don't know how to use MigrateWubi... how did you do it?

Comment: @Braiam gnome-disks utility shows all the information, it showed me that C drive on windows was sda2 on Ubuntu, and D on windows was sda3 on Ubuntu. Explore the utility you will find the answer.
You should see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MigrateWubi this shows how to use migrate wubi.

Comment: The caveat here is that gnome-disk don't detail the partitions by letters, in fact it uses `sda1`, `sda2`, `sda#` for partitions on the same disk and `sda`, `sdb`, `sdc`, `sdX` for differentiating disks. If I find the same problem as you did, your answer will not solve my issue. So, please, [edit] your answer, and describe the entire procedure, if it's possible with screenshots.